# Explicit Taylor Expansions of Zeta Function

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, analytic-continuation

If one's goal were to calculate one value of the zeta function, say $\zeta(-1)$ is at all feasible to do this explicitly by calculating Taylor series and doing an analytic continuation "by hand" - or will the work involved therein be tantamount to developing e.g. the functional equation given below?

Suppose you start with $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$ which is defined on the real line for $s > 1$ and your goal is to calculate some other value of the analytic continuation, say at $s = -1$.   I've read many great expositions that ultimately lead to the functional equation $$\zeta(s) = 2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin(\frac{\pi s}{2}) \Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s).$$ The derivations aren't too bad, and as a partial solution, it is quite direct (albeit somewhat clever) to extend $\zeta(s)$ with the $\eta$ function, which would work if you wanted to evaluate somewhere with $\mathrm{Re}(s)\geq 0$.

Anyways, to my question:  In theory, without much ingenuity, one could do the following:

1. Note that the given definition for $\zeta(s)$ defines an analytic function on the half plane Re$(s) \geq 1$.   We've extended $\zeta(s)$ a bit.
2. We calculate the Taylor series for $\zeta(s)$ at the point $s=6+12i$. One would discover a radius of convergence of $13$.  Doing so requires either calculating derivatives or could be done by integration.
3. One has now extended $\zeta(s)$ to include e.g. the point $s = -4+12i$.  One could then calculate the Taylor series around that point and would find a radius of convergence of $13$ once again.
4. This last Taylor series would be sufficient for calculating $\zeta(-1)$.

Are these calculations feasible? I suppose by that I mean, would we be able to write down enough detail in steps 2 and 3 so that in step 4 we could see that $\zeta(-1) = -1/12$?    I'm wondering if perhaps the answer to this question is:  Yes, but in doing so, you would essentially develop everything in the functional equation above. It's no "easier" to do it this way.  Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: No idea what you mean with "are these calculations feasible". You need to do infinitely many computations, if so then yes you recover exactly $-1/12$. Once you know some lower bounds for the abscissa of convergence and some upper bounds for $|\zeta|$, you can do approximate calculations, computing and approximating only finitely many  terms of the Taylor series, to recover some approximations to $\zeta(-1)$. Also did you realize that $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ is entire, its Taylor series have infinite radius of convergence.

Comment: Proving that $\zeta(-k)=(-1)^k B_{k+1}/(k+1)$ is rather easy from $\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$.

Comment: The Taylor series at any point has a radius of convergence distance to closest singularity which in this case is $1$ so to get from the half plane $\Re s >1$ to $-1$ two steps are good enough

Comment: Thanks! @Conrad, that's how I calculated the radii of convergence for the two steps that I did.

Comment: Thanks @reuns I guess by "feasible" I mean at the end could you get a reasonable sum that you could calculate.  I guess a positive answer would be "yes - here is a reference that does something similar. The sums simplify by using X."  I was just wondering if anyone had done this sort of calculation in this detail.